# Can a computer be used as a headset with bluetooth?

Tags: qt, bluetooth, headset, qtbluetooth

With Qt Bluetooth module (qt 5.2 and up) is it possible to use a Linux computer as a audio gateway?

Basically, I want to use computer as a headset and handle digital audio which comes from a mobile phone and send digital audio over bluetooth using qt bluetooth api.

If this isn't posibble to be done with qtbluetooth which api can handle it?

Comment: it should be possible. You have to provide Bluetooth server with respective profiles, like: HSP, HFP. Check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#List_of_profiles) and its references.

Comment: Yes it seems possible how and which api qt has a bluetooth api but doesnt have any information about hsp or hfp just spp also I couldn't find any api that can do that with explanation.